# AVPlayer + FairPlay + Offline, possible on MacOS X?

Tags: macos, avplayer, fairplay

I have watched the WWDC session "Whats New in HTTP Live Streaming" https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/504/ where it is described how to use `AVPlayer` for offline FairPlay playback.

A look at the documentation however seems to imply this is only possible for iOS (not MacOS) as all the classes described are iOS10 Only.

Is this not possible for MacOS? Any sources to confirm either way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually this question was posted on Apple Developer Forums and the response is that

> Offline HLS is only supported on iOS at this time. Please do file an
>   enhancement request at bugreporter.apple.com if you have use cases for
>   macOS as well, including some details of the use case.

The thread is here : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5529